# Java combinatorics. Creating an object with generated data

Tags: java, combinatorics

This is my first post in here. Today I started using combinatoric library for Java.

This one: https://github.com/dpaukov/combinatoricslib3

I've got more than 10k length of sides of triangle in Excel. Than i pulled them into 2d Integer array.

Than i created class Triangle:

```
public class Triangle {

private int a;
private int b;
private int c;

public Triangle(int a, int b, int c)
{
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
}

public boolean isCorrect()
{
    if(this.a + this.b > this.c)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

}

My problem is that I can generate all possible combinations of Triangles but have no idea how to created object Triangle. Only know how to print result.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    Generator.combination(sides).simple(3).stream().forEach(System.out::println);



}
```

Thank you in advance. Cheers!

EDIT:

This is example of sides:

```
static final int[][] sides = new int[][]{

        {71, 100, 1231, 832, 127},
        {336, 447, 815, 658, 373},
        {126, 444, 556, 221, 1322},
        {1226, 662, 985, 87, 991},
        {555, 512, 111, 339, 22},
    };
```

I want to generate all possible Triangles with this data.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: you are using **int** all over the place, and some streaming calls might to autoboxing. So be aware about potential hidden performance costs for switching between int and Integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should look something like that:

```
Generator
.combination(sides)
.simple(3)
.stream()
.forEach(
     sides -> new Triangle(sides[0],sides[1],sides[2])
);
```

Note that this implies that the sides are *integer*, if not (e.g. strings) you might need to additionally convert (map) them to a proper type.

Now, if you want for example to collect them all to list, you can do:

```
List<Triangle> triangles = Generator
    .combination(sides)
    .simple(3)
    .stream()
    .map(sides -> new Triangle(sides[0],sides[1],sides[2]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

You can iterate over a two-dimensional *int[][]* array, and find all the combinations for each *line*, like that:

```
Arrays.stream(sides)
    .forEach(
    line -> {
         Generator.combination(Arrays.stream(line).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .simple(3)
        .stream()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
);
```

Comment: Would you please provide a sample of your original code output (i.e. _forEach(System.out::println)_), just a few lines will do.

Comment: I just noticed that it not prints my numbers.

Comment: Btw this is original code. Using sides array as a temporary help instead of 10k ints from Excel.

Comment: AFAIK Generator.combination(sides) expects a flat list of arguments, not a 2-dimensional array, like you have (at least that what javadoc says).

Try it like that:

Generator.combination(71, 100, 1231, 832, 127)
.....

and see if it works for you

Comment: My teacher showed example with 2-dimensional array. But he created quadrangles. This is just implementation problem.

Comment: I've provided an example of how you can iterate over all the lines of your two-dimensional array, and find all the combinations for an each line (see update).

Now that you know how to do this, and how to create Triangle objects, you should be well able to complete your assignment (not going to take all the fun out of it ;) )